# Save plot options in list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I wonder if it is possible to make a variable that holds info obout wanted style for Show[] function. So ewery time i want to display plots in Show[] i will insert that variable in Show[] to set options for style.

I want something like this...

```
OPTIONS=
     AxesOrigin -> Automatic,
     LabelStyle -> Directive[14, Black, Bold, Italic],
     ImageSize -> {450}

    Show[
     ListLinePlot[data],
     OPTIONS
     ]
```

The solution is simple but im green. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OPTIONS = {AxesOrigin -> Automatic, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[14, Red, Bold, Italic], ImageSize -> {450}}

Show[ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], OPTIONS]
```

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks i didnt know what i must do with the "," :)

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `Show` with options to graphics automatically using `$Post`, e.g.

```
$Post := With[{opts = {
     AxesOrigin -> Automatic,
     LabelStyle -> Directive[14, Black, Bold, Italic],
     ImageSize -> {250}}},
  If[Head[#] === Graphics, Show[#, opts], #] &]

ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

[image]

Restoring `$Post` to default:

```
$Post =.
```